# How to selectively apply borders to a docx table in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

In Microsoft Word, if you go to the properties of a table, and then the "Borders and Shading" section, you will see that you are able to apply borders to a table on 8 of its aspects. *top, bottom, left, right, center-vertical, center-horizontal, diagonal-left, and diagonal-right*

How can I turn them on selectively using POI?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In current `apache poi 4.1.0` the class [XWPFTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html) provides methods for this.

For example [XWPFTable.setTopBorder](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html#setTopBorder-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType-int-int-java.lang.String-):

```
public void setTopBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType type,
                         int size,
                         int space,
                         java.lang.String rgbColor)

Set Top borders for table

Parameters:
    type - - XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType e.g. single, double, thick
    size - - Specifies the width of the current border. The width of this border is 
             specified in measurements of eighths of a point, with a minimum value of two 
             (onefourth of a point) and a maximum value of 96 (twelve points). 
             Any values outside this range may be reassigned to a more appropriate value.
    space - - Specifies the spacing offset that shall be used to place this border 
              on the table
    rgbColor - - This color may either be presented as a hex value (in RRGGBB format), 
                 or auto to allow a consumer to automatically determine the border color 
                 as appropriate.
```

See [XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.html) for possible border types.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordTableBorders {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table:");

  //create the table
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(3,3);
  table.setWidth("100%");
  for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    table.getRow(row).getCell(col).setText("row " + row + ", col " + col);
   }
  }

  //set borders
  table.setTopBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.THICK_THIN_LARGE_GAP, 32, 0, "FF0000");
  table.setBottomBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.THICK_THIN_LARGE_GAP, 32, 0, "FF0000");
  table.setLeftBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.THICK_THIN_LARGE_GAP, 32, 0, "FF0000");
  table.setRightBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.THICK_THIN_LARGE_GAP, 32, 0, "FF0000");
  table.setInsideHBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.DOT_DASH, 16, 0, "00FF00");
  table.setInsideVBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.DOTTED, 24, 0, "0000FF");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("create_table.docx"); 
  document.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: My version of POI appears to only have the setInsideHBorder() and setInsideVBorder() methods

Comment: @Ebony Maw: And what version is it? And why not updating to version `4.1.0` then?

Comment: It appears to be version 3.8 - it's a government project so I don't have the ability to make this change :(

Comment: @Ebony Maw: Sorry but that version is too old (Mar 2012). I will not bothering myself with that old version.